# Cannot copy/paste to Windows 7 after an amount of time

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, copy-paste

A user on my network (after some hours of work) is unable to use copy/paste on their Windows 7 machine, either with right clicking or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. The system is fairly new, so malware problems are unlikely. The machine is under group policy, but I don't think it matters because it is the only one.

I'd hope to only use Windows repair as a last solution. Are there any fixes such as using ClipX or are they based on the Windows clipboard?

**Updated**

I re-installed Windows and the problem still persists. I have found this [**article**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/cannot-copy-and-paste-in-windows-7/c572a1b3-5d8f-48b3-8b69-94695cf32710) however, it didn't work.

I called HP Tech support and they had me to remove the following file from the Windows registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\appinit_dlls.
```

But it didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't rule out malware based only on the age of the system - though Win7 is much better hardened than WinXP, it's still not immune.  Also, *what* is 'under group policy'?  Does your user make heavy use of RDP connections to other systems, as this can be an issue with clipboard use?

Comment: If they were to look at the clipboard in word, or other program, what would they see?

Comment: No, the users make simple word-excel-email procedures. RDP no, but they execute an application via our server(with a shortcut. Yes its horrible) if it helps. @soandos I want to look at the clipboard, but win7 doesnt support clipbrd.exe. Does it?

Comment: You user's computer is obviously in need of being restored.  Why are you trying to "work around the problem" you shouldn't ignore problems like being unable to hit ctrl-C.

Comment: So, you think a repair is better? A temporary solution like clipX wont work?

Comment: ClipX uses the Windows Clipboard.

Comment: Is there any third party software like Teracopy? Try to remove it and then check or repair/re-install the teracopy again.

Comment: And also try to disable the Aero and then restart the system and then check and post your reply.